# blocked:csp error in angular 8 app with chrome extension

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I want to add a whole angular 8 app into chrome extension with content script (not in popup), i have added a manifest file with content-security policy like

```
content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; default-src 'self' http://*;"
```

but still get error when fire a http request on server

```
Refused to connect to <request_url> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' data: blob: <url> <url> <url>"
```

this is happend only in angular app because normal html javacript and ajax request works fine, but when i load angular app chrome blocked this request.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have in manifest:

```
connect-src self * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:;
```

But in the violation you have got:

```
Refused to connect to <request_url> because it violates the following CSP directive:
"connect-src 'self' data: blob: <url> <url> <url>"
```

Either you are editing not that manifest that use in the extension, or you are using invalid sources, and Google removes them.

Google's manifest V2 documentation is broken, but AFAIK there is some limitations on using the `content_security_policy` key:

- `'unsafe-inline'` is not allowed, to execute inline scripts it need to use their `'hash-value'` in the `script-src` directive.
- External sources must have https: scheme, use http: is not valid.
- All sources must have a host defined, except `blob:`, `filesystem:` and `https:`.

Quite possible thst's a reason why `connect-src *` does not wort inside the extension. Try to use https://<request_url> instead of `*`;

Comment: is there a possibility that angular app put content-security-policy when run? if yes then where angular set this? or this might be from parent site then how to change that?

Comment: Negative. Extension uses CSP from manifest only. Angular can't change the manifest file. Try to use `https://example.com` host source instead of `*`. Where `https://example.com` is a host source to which Angular makes an XMLHttpRequest/ajax reguest.